# How to implement OpenID in Angular 4

Tags: angular, openid

I'm building an application with Angular 4 that I want to integrate with Steam.

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around openID and how to use it to get a user's 64-bit Steam ID. This is going badly. I've found the TypeScript lib on openID's website and installed it to my app but steam says I need to set `http://steamcommunity.com/openid` as the provider.

Having looked thoroughly over the documentation for the Angular 4 OpenID lib I can't find "provider" anywhere D:

Then again, I'm not even sure I'm using the right library! (OpenID mentions "obsolete specifications such as OpenID 2" which I'm pretty sure is what Steam uses)

How can I proceed with this? Or is there a simpler API for accessing steam with OpenID?

### Edit

Here's the code for the config, which is where I realised I didn't understand what I was doing anymore:

```
export class AppModule {
constructor(public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {

    let openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration = new OpenIDImplicitFlowConfiguration();
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.stsServer = 'https://localhost:44318';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.redirect_url = 'https://localhost:44311';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.client_id = 'angularclient';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.response_type = 'id_token token';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.scope = 'openid email profile';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.post_logout_redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:44311/Unauthorized';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.startup_route = '/home';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.forbidden_route = '/Forbidden';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.unauthorized_route = '/Unauthorized';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.log_console_warning_active = true;
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.log_console_debug_active = false;
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds = 10;
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.override_well_known_configuration = false;
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.override_well_known_configuration_url = 'https://localhost:44386/wellknownconfiguration.json';
    // openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.storage = localStorage;

    this.oidcSecurityService.setupModule(openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code what you tried and what errors you got  ?

Comment: I'll provide the code for the config, which is where I got stuck, from reading steam I thought there'd be a `doLoginForProvider(provider)` function (or something along those lines), but I got about 20 lines of config instead and no clear documentation (that I could see) to explain it :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't even putting the code in the correct file or against correct class **[app.component.ts i.e. AppComponent](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular2-oauth-oidc-demo/blob/master/app/app.component.ts)** should contain that stuff.

You should download the [zip](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular2-oauth-oidc-demo/archive/master.zip) or better still use Git and check it out from https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular2-oauth-oidc-demo.git

Comment: Thanks, I get how it works now....umm, is this backwards compatible to work with an openID 2 provider rather than OIDC?